# Can I specify conditional default values for a parameter in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, parameters, default-value

I thought if this was possible it might work using parameter sets so I tried the following:

```
Function New-TestMultipleDefaultValues {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Default1")]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName="Default1")]$SomeOtherThingThatIfSpecifiedShouldResultInTest1HavingValue1,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Default1")]$Test1 = "Value1",
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Default2")]$Test1 = "Value2"
    )
    $PSBoundParameters
}
```

Executing this to create the function results in the error `Duplicate parameter $test1 in parameter list.` so it doesn't look like this way is an option.

The only thing I can think of at this point is to do something like this:

```
Function New-TestMultipleDefaultValues {
    param (
        $SomeOtherThingThatIfSpecifiedShouldResultInTest1HavingValue1,
        $Test1
    )
    if (-not $Test1 -and $SomeOtherThingThatIfSpecifiedShouldResultInTest1HavingValue1) {
        $Test1 = "Value1"
    } elseif (-not $Test1 -and -not $SomeOtherThingThatIfSpecifiedShouldResultInTest1HavingValue1) {
        $Test1 = "Value2"
    }

    $Test1
}
```

Which works but seems ugly:

```
PS C:\Users\user> New-TestMultipleDefaultValues -SomeOtherThingThatIfSpecifiedShouldResultInTest1HavingValue1 "thing"
Value1
PS C:\Users\user> New-TestMultipleDefaultValues
Value2
PS C:\Users\user> New-TestMultipleDefaultValues -Test1 "test"
test
```

Any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work:

<sup>Since there is then no longer a need for explicit parameter sets, I've omitted them; without specific properties, the `[Parameter()]` attributes aren't strictly needed anymore either.</sup>

```
Function New-TestMultipleDefaultValues {

  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [Parameter()] $SomeOtherThing,
    [Parameter()] $Test1 = 
      ('Value2', 'Value1')[$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SomeOtherThing')]
  )
    
  # * As expected, if -Test1 <value> is explicitly specified, 
  #   parameter variable $Test1 receives that value.
  # * If -Test1 is omitted, the expression assigns 'Value1` to $Test1
  #   if -SomeOtherThing was specified, and 'Value2' otherwise.
  $Test1 # Output the effective value of $Test1

}
```

- It is possible to use *expressions* as parameter default values.

  - The above code *is* an expression and therefore can be used as-is.
  - To use a single *command* (a call to a PowerShell cmdlet, function, script or to an external program) as an expression, enclose it in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--).
  - In all other cases you need `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) (or `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)) to convert the code to an expression; these cases are:

    - A `Throw` statement (and, hypothetically, `exit` and `return` statements, but you wouldn't use them in this context)
    - A compound construct such as `foreach`, `while`, ...
    - *Multiple* commands, expressions, or compound constructs, separated with `;`
- However, it is safe to *always* use `$(...)` (or `@(...)`) to enclose the code that calculates the default value, which you may opt to do for simplicity.
- These expressions are evaluated *after* the explicitly specified parameters have been bound, which allows an expression to examine what parameters have been bound, via the automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable:

  - `('Value2', 'Value1')[$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SomeOtherThing')]` is simply a more concise reformulation of
    `if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SomeOtherThing')) { 'Value1' } else { 'Value2' }`
    that takes advantage of `[bool]` values mapping onto `0` (`$false`) and `1` (`$true`) when used as an array index (integer).
  - In PowerShell v7+ you could use a *ternary conditional* instead, which has the added advantage of short-circuiting the evaluation:
    `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SomeOtherThing') ? 'Value1' : 'Value2'`

Comment: Thanks. Surrounding the conditional default value with $ outside parentheses is got me what I wanted.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SubjectiveReality; I've since realized that `$(...)` is often not needed: expressions can be used as-is, single commands can be enclosed in `(...)`. However, given that these distinctions may not be obvious, categorically using `$(...)` is an option - please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at dynamic parameters. You declare a section called dynamicparams {} and inside you can create parameters on the fly.